# how to pass json data other view controller

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2

Hi all am getting a data from server i.e:

```
{


  error = 0;

  "error_msg" = "Successfully Login";

 success = 1;

  user =     {

  DriverID = 35;

 DriverName = "Home  nath";

"com_id" = 2;

};

}
```

now i need to pass data of DriverName to other view controller in label box.how to do this one??

Comment: It's more helpful if you post what you already tried in order to solve it and what error you're getting.

Comment: i have almost done with calling url printing url and object getting from the server..now i cant able to print particular object.for that i have tried:  var result = jsonResults["error_msg"] as? String
                print("rest:\(result)")

Comment: you can upvote my answer if it helps you:-)

Answer (score 2):

*create a variable of type string in your destination view controller.*

**DestinationViewController.Swift**

```
class DestinationViewController: UIViewController {

    var driverName: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(driverName)

    }
}
```

**CurrentViewController.swift**

In your CurrentViewController override `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.

```
class CurrentViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destnationVC = segue.destination as! DestinationViewController
        destnationVC.driverName = "Home nath"
    }

}
```

learn how to pass data from CurrentViewController to DestinationViewController and DestinationViewController to OrignViewController it ll help you lot.

refer [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers).

Comment: i want to fetch key option not particular name like homenath

Comment: so you have to parse the data first.

Comment: first help me print driver name in same controller....then i will parse that to other controller....thanks

Comment: var result = jsonResults["DriverName"] as? String
                        print("rest:\(result)")
i tried this but it printing as nil value

Comment: Your json data is not in correct format. you can validate your json here. http://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator

Comment: First you have to convert it to dictionary object using `let jsonDataDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? NSDictionary`

Comment: `do {
                let jsonDataDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? NSDictionary
                
                //Work with your json dictionary.

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }`